# Active Admin custom 400, 500 error pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

How would you implement custom 400 and 500 error pages in active admin? The pages must use the active admin layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

into your routes:

```
match "/404", to: "errors#render_error"
match "/500", to: "errors#render_error"
```

build new controller called `ErrorsController`

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController

  def render_error
    exception   = env["action_dispatch.exception"]
    status_code = ActionDispatch::ExceptionWrapper.new(env, exception).status_code

    @method, @message = if status_code == 404
      ["not_found", env["REQUEST_URI"]]
    else
      ["server_error", "#{exception.message}\n#{exception.backtrace.join('\n')}"]
    end

    render status: status_code
  end
end
```

then in your ApplicationController:

```
private

  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
  end
```

then create new view to show any html you want.

hope it helps you.

Comment: Part of question is that pages must use the active admin layout.

Comment: it's a good answer but I need to know how to use the active admin layout for the custom error pages. It looks like it's not a trivial problem

Comment: not a problem when create a view use activeadmin layout from the controller http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977149/activeadmin-custom-views-which-retain-the-activeadmin-layout