# Custom active admin page with index action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I'm using rails 3, I have custom active admin page called "current_details",
I have created controller in the admin page:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Current Details" do

controller do

def index
  @milestones =  Milestone.all
  @collection =  @milestones.select{|a| a.milestone_status == false}
  @current_details = @collection.select{ |a| a.delivery_date.to_date.strftime('%m%Y') == Date.today.strftime('%m%Y') or a.delivery_date.to_date.strftime('%m%Y') < Date.today.strftime('%m%Y') }          
end
end

content only: :index do
   render 'index'
end
end
```

I need the index action for this, How do I get that?

I already tried with rendering partial, It's throwing error as: Missing partial admin/current_details/index.
I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18977149/activeadmin-custom-views-which-retain-the-activeadmin-layout)
Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: does active admin generates own layout too ?

Comment: I need active admin layout too with index.

Comment: I does generates @7urkm3n

Comment: I have never used gem activeadmin. I just dnt know how that gem works.

Comment: @7urkm3n For more details you can  refer ->  [activeadmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure you have `_index.html.erb` file

```
views/admin/myname/_index.html.erb
```